# Error setting up Docker Compose interpreter in PyCharm: 'executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I am trying to set up a Django project in PyCharm on Ubuntu and configure the Docker Compose interpreter.  However, when I try to create the interpreter ([Step 6](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote)), I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "Creating djanog_web_run ... ": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

I have confirmed that the docker-compose up command runs the program properly, and my Docker Compose file looks fine. It is shown below:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I have also followed the steps to set up a Docker Compose interpreter in PyCharm (specifying the configuration files, service, and environment variables).

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

- PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Professional Edition)

Comment: Your Ubuntu host should already have a Python interpreter.  Can you use that directly?  (It still make sense to use Docker for a project-specific database.)

Comment: I usually create and develop docker-compose interpreter on Mac. I would like to port my development environment to Ubuntu. Therefore, using Python directly on Ubuntu is not an option for me. I followed this manual to set it up, but I get the above error at step 6.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote

Comment: I have the same error, i am trying to set up a vanilla python project, so no django

Comment: Hello Jan! I think this error happen on any docker images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Docker-Desktop, make sure Compose V2 is enabled in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker | Tools in PyCharm.

[image: PyCharm - Settings - Tools]

Comment: Done, still not working for me

Comment: It helped me! Thanks alot! Hi Jorge Arévalo how about configure Docker setting. Theare are also Use Compose V2 setting. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem today. When I ran

```
me@mycomputer:~/myProject$ docker run -it my-image:latest /bin/bash

nobody@c2ae150852f5:/opt$ which python
/opt/venv/bin/python
```

I found out, that my image does not have a system interpreter, but a virtual environment. So choosing that in [Step 6](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#57d196e1) and giving the path `/opt/venv/bin/python` I was able to connect.

After entering the path via the 3 dots, it needs to be selected in the drop down. For me it showed as `[invalid] /opt/venv/bin/python`. It worked anyway.

Using PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Professional Edition).

Hope it helps!